# Whether the graphs G and G' given below are isomorphic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Whether the graphs G and G' given below are isomorphic?

[image]

Comment: An isomorphism preserves paths...

Comment: Hint: on the left, drag vertices $a,c,e$ up until...

Comment: count connected components

Comment: what are the conditions for isomorphic ???

Comment: An isomorphism is a bijective function $f$ between the respective sets of vertices such that there is an edge $(a,b)$ iff there is an edge $(f(a),f(b))$.

Answer (score 1):

As step 0, recall the notion of [isomorphism of graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism). It is a trivial fact that if two graphs are isomorphic, then their connected components have the same number. But $G$ is not connected, but $G'$ is connected. Alternatively, find the minimal length of a cycle in $G$ resp. $G'$.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following is enough to show that $G\ncong G'$.

$1$.$K_3 \subseteq G$ while $K_3 \nsubseteq G'$

$2$. $G$ is disconeccted while $G'$ is connected

$3$. $P_4, P_5, P_6 \subseteq G'$ while $P_4, P_5, P_6 \nsubseteq G$